# C# SQL table id increment?

Tags: c#, sql-server, increment

C# windows form:

I have a button that adds an order to a MS SQL table. My problem is that each order gets a new orderid.
I want it to only give it a different id when another button is clicked.

Here is the code that adds orders:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=" + globalvariables.hosttxt + "," + globalvariables.porttxt + "\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=ha;Persist Security Info=false; UID='" + globalvariables.user + "' ; PWD='" + globalvariables.psw + "'"); 
SqlCommand command = con.CreateCommand();

command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO bestillinger (bruger,oprettet,cpr,navn,kk,antal,firma,ha,farve,udlevering,levering) VALUES (@bruger,@oprettet,@cpr,@navn,@kk,@antal,@firma,@ha,@farve,@udlevering,@levering) Select SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bruger", globalvariables.user);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oprettet", DateTime.Now);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cpr", (textBox1.Text + "-" + textBox2.Text));
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@navn", textBox3.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kk", textBox4.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@antal", comboBox4.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firma", comboBox1.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ha", listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@farve", comboBox3.Text);

if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
{
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@udlevering", dateTimePicker1.Value.Date);
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@levering", dateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(-7).Date);
}
else
{
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@udlevering", DBNull.Value);
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@levering", DBNull.Value);
}

con.Open();
var nyordre = command.ExecuteScalar();
con.Close();
```

Comment: And where is another button then?

Comment: Are you saying you want to insert a new row but not assign a new value for nyordre?  That is not possible with an identity column.  You might consider a SEQUENCE instead.

Comment: Yes, add a new row with the same nyordre id. OR else insert these nyordre id's in another table with a reference id-column.

Comment: You should separate the logic of your orders internal system identification and the order number the customer/company see. Order number logic is often a business logic dependant thing whereas the internal id (database id) is not. So use identity or guid for your orderid but have a column for the order number. That makes it easy to do what you're trying to do and will provide other benefits as well

Comment: Usually, a single order may contain many items. food for thought.

Comment: *Separate* the Order/Invoice ID from the *primary key*. In general, you should *not* use the primary key to hold business logic. Second, you don't need `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` at the end. `INSERT` has an [OUTPUT clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql#examples)  that can return the new ID, eg `INSERT ... OUTPUT inserted.ID VALUES (...)`